# Multiple dropdown filters for table in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to have a table in vue (bootstrapVue) and I want to apply several filters at once with dropdown menues above the table. But when I chose an option in the second dropdown the first one gets reset. This is probably very easy, but I'm a beginner and I don't get how to do it...

This is my table:

```
<b-table show-empty
         stacked="md"
         responsive
         hover:true
         :items="items"
         :fields="fields"
         :current-page="currentPage"
         :per-page="perPage"
         :filter="filter"
         :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
         :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
         @filtered="onFiltered">
```

This is my dropdown:

```
<b-form-select v-model="filter" :options="city" class="mb-3" ></b-form-select>
```

The filter option is a build-in function I guess. Is the solution to dublicate it with another name and use it for the next dropdown?

My Data looks like this:

```
const items = [{name: 'Der Kotti', kategorie: 'Spielplatz', stadt: 'Hamburg', straße: 'Kottwitzstraße', datum: moment('2018/02/15').format('D.M.Y'), tageszeit: 'Morgens & Nachmittags', alter: 'Alle Altersgruppen', link: '', drinnen: 'Draußen', gruppe: '', sprache: '', regelmäßigkeit: ''}]
```

I used something like this in a different project:

```
$('#table-filter-category').on('change', function(){
  table.search(this.value).draw();
});
```

But I don't know how to use this approach in the current project...

Here are all my dropdown filters:

```
    <b-row>
  <b-col lg="2" offset-lg="2" md="6" class="my-1">
    <h5 style="text-align:left">Stadt:</h5>
    <b-form-select v-model="filter" :options="city" class="mb-3" ></b-form-select>
  </b-col>
  <b-col lg="2" md="6" class="my-1">
    <h5 style="text-align:left">Kategorie:</h5>
    <b-form-select v-model="filter" :options="cat" class="mb-3" ></b-form-select>
  </b-col>
  <b-col lg="2" md="6" class="my-1">
    <h5 style="text-align:left">Tageszeit:</h5>
    <b-form-select v-model="filter" :options="daytime" class="mb-3" ></b-form-select>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

Edit:

Ok, so after a while I figured out how to write my own filter function. I put it in the 'computed:' section in my .vue file.

```
filteredData: function(){
  let filterData = this.data

  if (this.checkCity.length > 0){
    filterData = filterData.filter(data => {
      return this.checkCity.includes(data.stadt)
    })
  }

  return filterData
}
```

Where `data` is my original data input, `filteredData` is the filtered data and `checkCity`is for example a checkbox with the `key` that I want to filter for. `checkCity` is used in the `v-model` of the checkbox.

Comment: You mention two dropdowns. Can you show the other?

Comment: Consider having `filter` be a `computed` property, while your two dropdowns use some `filter1` and `filter2` in order to calculate what `filter` should be. Or, of course, as many dropdowns and filters as you need using the same general concept.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for, but I guess I just don't know how to write the filter function.

Comment: How should `filter` be? An object? A string? A regex? A function?

Comment: The `filter` should look if the value of a certain key is a certain string.